# DiscordAPIError: Missing Access But The Bot Already Has All Permissions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was coding a Discord bot, and everything was fine. However, when I update discord.js from 13.8.0 to 13.8.1 and try to give members role by clicking button and submit a modal, it shows this error:

```
/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
  throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
        ^
DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js:124:7)
at async /app/events/guild/modalSubmit.js:10:7 {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/926089413933539359/members/606668363531288577/roles/926252511201988678',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

I've checked the permissions of the bot, but it already had all permissions.

Code of the modalSubit:

```
const response = modal.getTextInputValue('verification-input');
if(response.toLowerCase()!=="lock"){
  await modal.reply({content:"Failed!",ephemeral: true});
  return;
}
modal.guild.roles.fetch('926252511201988678')
  .then(async role=>{
  await modal.member.roles.add(role);
})
await modal.reply({content:"Finished!",ephemeral: true});
 }
```

Comment: Is this running as a selfbot or as its own account?

Comment: can you show us the code for the button?

Comment: @AaronMeese Sorry, but I don't understand the differences between them

Comment: @RamyHazem The button will call a modal, so I will show the code of the modal.

Comment: @Tobydog0501 did you have to get your Discord token from your console or did you create a separate bot account for your server?

Comment: @AaronMeese I only have one bot in my server, I got the token from discord developers portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I figure it out. The bot joined a 2FA server, without a 2FA account creating it. I found this out by clicking another button which shows an error like this:

```
/rbd/pnpm-volume/d50c9aa3-e1b3-4f3c-a369-a5ec640ad85c/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Two factor is required for this operation
    at RequestHandler.execute (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d50c9aa3-e1b3-4f3c-a369-a5ec640ad85c/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d50c9aa3-e1b3-4f3c-a369-a5ec640ad85c/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildChannelManager.create (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d50c9aa3-e1b3-4f3c-a369-a5ec640ad85c/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildChannelManager.js:157:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta make sure your bot's highest role is **above** the role you're trying to add in the guild hierarchy

[image: example role setup]